# VideoView blocks background sound

Tags: android, android-videoview, resume, pause

1) I have added VideoView but And the background music (example: Spotify, phone music app sound) is blocked while playing video How can I cancel it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `VideoView#setAudioFocusRequest(int)` method.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#setAudioFocusRequest(int)

Comment: The problem with `videoView.setAudioFocusRequest(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_NONE)` is that it's only for api >= 26